# Can a Selenium Grid 2 Node Json config file point to multiple hub / Servers?

Tags: selenium, configuration, automation, grid, webdriver

I was wondering if there is a way to register a single Selenium Grid 2 Node to multiple hubs, using a json configuration file for this.

I was thinking something like this:

```
{
"capabilities":
    [
            {
                    "browserName":"firefox",
                    "maxInstances":5,
                    "platform":"LINUX"
            },
            {
                    "browserName":"chrome",
                    "maxInstances":5,
                    "platform":"LINUX"
            }
    ],
"configuration":
    {
            "cleanUpCycle":2000,
            "timeout":30000,
            "maxSession":5,
            "url_hub_1":"http://10.254.254.40:4444/wd/hub",
            "url_hub_2":"http://10.254.254.40:4444/wd/hub",
            "url_hub_3":"http://10.254.254.40:4444/wd/hub",
            "url_hub_4":"http://10.254.254.40:4444/wd/hub",

    }
}
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated.
Regards!

Comment: I almost have it working but not quite.  Maybe you will get some ideas from my project: https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/tree/master/root